# SQL COUNT() Returning 0 When Dividing

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a really quick & simple report for a client.  I am sure I have some syntax wrong since the result of the % is always 0.  Here is the SQL and the sample result set:

```
DECLARE @TotalCount INT
SELECT @TotalCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE OrderCompleteFlag = 1)
PRINT @TotalCount

SELECT '21 - 25', COUNT(1) AS 'COUNT', (COUNT(1) / @TotalCount) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 21 and 35 AND OrderCompleteFlag = 1
UNION
SELECT '26 - 30', COUNT(1) AS 'COUNT', (COUNT(1) / @TotalCount) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 26 and 30 AND OrderCompleteFlag = 1
```

Results:

```
11175

21 - 25 7631    0
26 - 30 3544    0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thx!

Dennis

```
*** UPDATE ***

The quick fix (on SQL SERVER) was to just declare @TotalCount as 
DECIMAL or NUMERIC.  thanks to everyone that helped solve with input! :)
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data for local reproduction?

Comment: `DECLARE @TotalCount NUMERIC(15, 5)` Just idea!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server - the issue was NUMERIC/DECIMAL.  Either fixes it.  thx!

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the numbers you are dividing to decimals.

TRY:

```
DECLARE @TotalCount INT
SELECT @TotalCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE OrderCompleteFlag = 1)
PRINT @TotalCount

SELECT '21 - 25', COUNT(1) AS 'COUNT', (COUNT(1) / Cast(@TotalCount As Decimal)) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 21 and 35 AND OrderCompleteFlag = 1
UNION
SELECT '26 - 30', COUNT(1) AS 'COUNT', (COUNT(1) / Cast(@TotalCount As Decimal)) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 26 and 30 AND OrderCompleteFlag = 1
```

Comment: That was it.  I changed the "INT" to "DECIMAL" at the very top declaration and it worked.  THANKS!  Ugh, always something stupid.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the divisor to decimal, otherwise you are dividing by integer:

```
DECLARE @TotalCount INT
SELECT @TotalCount = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE OrderCompleteFlag = 1)
PRINT @TotalCount

SELECT '21 - 25', COUNT(1) AS 'COUNT', (COUNT(1) / CAST(@TotalCount AS FLOAT)) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 21 and 35 AND OrderCompleteFlag = 1
UNION
SELECT '26 - 30', COUNT(1) AS 'COUNT', (COUNT(1) / CAST(@TotalCount AS FLOAT)) FROM TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 26 and 30 AND OrderCompleteFlag = 1
```

Comment: Or declare it as float from the start

Answer (score 0):

As you have written the query, simply declare `@TotalCount` to be a floating point or decimal type:

```
declare @TotalCount float;
```

And leave the rest the same.

However, you can greatly simplify the query.  The following basically does what you want, but produces an extra row with the "other" age groups:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 21 and 25 THEN '21 - 25'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 26 and 30 THEN '26 - 30' 
        END) as AgeGroup,
       COUNT(*) AS "Count",
       COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)*1.0) OVER () as Ratio
FROM TABLE
WHERE OrderCompleteFlag = 1;
```

You can fix that problem with this clause:

```
HAVING MIN(DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE())) BETWEEN 21 and 30
```